# passing session parameters to another controller and validating them in springboot

Tags: java, file, session, spring-boot, modelattribute

I am trying to implement a text search from a file in springboot. I have been successful in uploading the file to a directory. But when I try to pass the searchword and the file 's name as a session attribute in the next controller. I am unable to implement the text search. I need to know how I can also validate that the correct values are being passed in the session parameters and how can I map it to a model attribute in the GET request handler for the result page?

This is the controller where I am getting the upload file and initializing the session parameters. 
FileUploadController.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"searchText","fileName"})
public class FileUploadController {

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUploadedFiles(ModelMap model) {
        return "uploadForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(required=true) String 
    searchText,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,ModelMap model) {
        try{
            storageService.store(file);
            if(!model.containsAttribute("searchText"))
                model.addAttribute("searchText", searchText);

            if(!model.containsAttribute("fileName"))
                model.addAttribute("fileName", file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "FAIL to upload " + 
            file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
            return "uploadForm";
        }
        return "resultData";
    }
}
```

This is the controller for the results Page

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/resultData")
@SessionAttributes({"searchText","fileName"})
public class ResultController {
    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;

    @Autowired
    WordSearchService service;

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processResult(@ModelAttribute("searchText") String 
                                searchText,@ModelAttribute("fileName") 
                                String fileName,ModelMap model){
        List<String> searchTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Getting results page");
        model.addAttribute("searchText", searchText);
        searchTexts = service.getList(searchText);
        System.out.println(searchText);

        model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        /*Reads the file based on the list of query words and results are 
          stored in the hashmap<String,String> lineSearch for storing the 
          lines containg the words and hashmap<String,Integer> word for 
          storing each query word with the number of times it appears in the 
          file */

        try(Stream<String> stream = 
        Files.lines(storageService.loadFile(fileName))){
            for(String temp : searchTexts)
                list = stream.filter(line->
                line.contains(temp)).collect(Collectors.toList());

             int total = 0;
             Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
             for(String temp: searchTexts){
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    String line = itr.next();
                    if(line.contains(temp)){
                        total = service.countWord(line, searchText);
                        service.insertWordCount(searchText,total);
                        service.insertLineSearch(line, searchText);

                        if(!model.containsAttribute("lineSearch")){
                            model.addAttribute("lineSearch", 
                            service.getLineSearch());
                        }
                        if(!itr.hasNext()){
                            if(!model.containsAttribute("word")){
                                model.addAttribute("word", 
                                service.getWordCount());
                            }
                            total = 0;
                        }
                    }   
                }
                stream.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "resultData";
    }
}
```

This is the uploading page uploadForm.html

```
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>

        <h2>Please upload the file to search for the word </h2>

        <div>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Enter Search Text:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="searchText"></input></td>           
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>File to upload:</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is the result page resultData.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
            <body>
            <h2>List All Uploaded Files</h2>
            <div>
                 <p><b>Searching for the query ${searchText} in the file 
                      ${fileName}</b>
                     The expected results from the API call is:</p>

                 <div th:each="searchWord : ${word}">
                 <table>
                 <tr>
                 <td th:text="${searchWord.key}"> - found </td> 
                 <td th:text="${searchWord.value}"> time(s)</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr th:each="Line:${lineSearch}">
                 <td th:text="${line.value}" 
                    th:unless="${line.value}!=${word.key}"></td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
                 </div>
            </div>    
        </body>
    </html>
```

In spring boot, it seems difficult to pass and assign the values of the session parameter to another parameter or model attribute inside the second controller's method. I took help from the following video for working with @SessionAttributes in springboot but I haven't been successful so far.

Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypkDzSjalRo